# If you ^Z from a process, it gets "stopped". How do you switch back in?

Tags: command-line, process, background-process, jobs

I accidentally "stopped" my `telnet` process.  Now I can neither "switch back" into it, nor can I kill it (it won't respond to `kill 92929`, where 92929 is the processid.)

So, my question is, if you have a stopped process on linux command line, how do you switch back into it, or kill it, without having to resort to `kill -9`?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The easiest way is to run [`fg`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/fg/) to bring it to the foreground:

```
$ help fg
fg: fg [job_spec]
    Move job to the foreground.

    Place the job identified by JOB_SPEC in the foreground, making it the
    current job.  If JOB_SPEC is not present, the shell's notion of the
    current job is used.

    Exit Status:
    Status of command placed in foreground, or failure if an error occurs.
```

Alternatively, you can run [`bg`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/bg/) to have it continue in the background:

```
$ help bg
bg: bg [job_spec ...]
    Move jobs to the background.

    Place the jobs identified by each JOB_SPEC in the background, as if they
    had been started with `&'.  If JOB_SPEC is not present, the shell's notion
    of the current job is used.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless job control is not enabled or an error occurs.
```

If you have just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>, then to bring the job back just run `fg` with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks!! I suppose this is the eq of Alt+Tab.  Do you know what happened as soon as I did `fg telnet` though. It said `Terminated`, presumably b/c of my previous `kill` cmd.

Comment: @bobobobo presumably, yes. Anyway, the `fg` does not need any arguments. If you have just hit `^Z`, run `fg` in the same terminal and it will bring back the 1st job.

Comment: What if I want to end the process?

Comment: @AaronFranke you `fg` it and then Ctrl+C to kill it.

Comment: What if I am running a script with multiple commands which Ctrl+C only terminates one of the commands at a time and I want to kill the entire script?

Comment: @AaronFranke please ask a new question, show an example of the code, and the expected behavior on your chosen operating system. Normally, Ctrl+C kills the command, the thing you had launched from the command line. This would be the script, not the commands in the script, so the Ctrl+C would kill everything.

Answer (score 82):

You can use [`jobs`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/jobs/) to list the suspended process. Take the example.  Start with a process:

```
$ sleep 3000
```

Then you suspend the process:

```
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 3000
```

You can list the process:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 3000
```

and bring it back to the foreground:

```
$ fg %1
sleep 3000
```

The `%1` corresponds to the `[1]` listed with the `jobs` command.

Answer (score 35):

You should be able to re-start a suspended process by using the `kill` command to send the process the CONTINUE signal, from the command-line, thus:

```
kill -CONT 92929
```

Comment: This will cause it to resume operation, but not to be brought to the foreground.

Comment: @bahamat Yes, quite true. One would still need to `fg` inside the original terminal. I like to -STOP and -CONT gui programs to save resources, but they are effectively running in the background anyway.

Comment: In case of `sleep` it will `kill` the process which is not what you want..;)

Comment: Maybe not the correct answer, but a very useful one ! I have a script that opens several terminals in order to execute several commands concurrently. When I press ctrl-z on a terminal where a shell was launched to execute a command given as a parameter, it will stop the command. `jobs` then shows an empty list. I don't understand why the list is empty, but this `kill -CONT` is the only solution I know in this case to resume the stopped process.